# How do I earn the achievement for completing Slime Rancher?

Tags: achievements, slime-rancher

I have gotten to the Glass Desert, done all of the Oases, and gotten to the broken portal with the message, but I didn’t get the achievement for finishing the game.

Does anyone know why not? What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you complete the glass desert and discover the final message, you must return to the ranch where there is a final email from Casey. Once you have read the email titled "Another Tour," you will unlock the achievement "The Adventure Continues" for completing adventure mode.

[Source](https://www.trueachievements.com/game/Slime-Rancher/walkthrough/8).